# Smart proxy manager

Tags: networking, proxy, reverse-proxy, http-proxy

For some reasons I need a tool which works like a proxy but it redirects the requests to different proxies based on their domain.

Imagine that proxy is running on port 3000 on localhost. We set this proxy on the code and code send different requests. I want this proxy to redirect the requests with domain google.com to be redirected to another proxy (say proxy 1). and other domains to (say proxy 2).

So this superproxy redirects requests with google domain to proxy 1 and other request to proxy 2.

Is there a pre built tool for doing this?

I searched the net and tried some tools like nginx proxy manager but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using chrome, try SwitchyOmega extension. I think that is what you need.
I'm also looking for a middleware that can integrated a group of http/socks5 proxies, and can rotate proxy by session or by some policy. But nothing found yet.